# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed - Angular API Get Request from .Net

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, api

I'm a on learning stage, and a little bit of a noob, sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm working on a Movie DB project, with movies from live API, Favorite list, JWT auth, etc. I'm now on the end part, have everything done so far, and have one problem. Every person who click's on see details about movie, the movie will be sent on my DB. And with this user can save movie to his favorite table (.net Crud operations). Everything work but when I want to get movies from a table that's between movies table and users table (favorite table many to many relation) I get a error in my swagger everything is working, and I can get every movie that's in favorite, but in angular I user *ngFor, and the error say that it must return a array, but I'm getting a Object, every other get request works only this one doesn't. Here is my code and error:

[image]
You can see I get everything I want in console, but UI is Error

Component .ts and HTML:

```
//HTML

<div *ngFor="let fav of requests" class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="{{fav.Poster}}" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text"> {{fav.Title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.Ts

```
export class FavoriteListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service: MovieService) { }
  requests: any = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFav();
  }

  getFav(){
    this.service.getFavorite1().subscribe(
      res => {
      this.requests = res;
      console.log(res)
    });
  }
}
```

MovieService

```
getFavorite1(){
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:5002/api/Favorite/getUsersFavorite').pipe(map(res => res));
  }
```

And this is my get request in .Net 5

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("getUsersFavorite")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersFavoriteMovies()
        {
            string userId = User.Claims.First(a => a.Type == "UserID").Value;
            var user = await _context.DbUsers.Where(n => n.Id == Int32.Parse(userId)).Select(movies => new FavoriteView()

            {
                ImdbId = movies.Favorites.Select(n => n.ImdbId).ToList(),
                Title = movies.Favorites.Select(n => n.Movies.Title).ToList(),
                Poster = movies.Favorites.Select(n => n.Movies.Poster).ToList()

            }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();


            return Ok(user);
        }
```

I tried a lot of thing, the closest I get is this, and when I change in .net request the .FirstOrDefaultAsync() to .ToListAsync(). When I it to ToListAsync I get this:

[image]

In this case I don't get any error but nothing is showing in UI

I know the question is big, but I'm desperate, I'm stuck on this a few day's, and every help is great. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this way, it will work.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="requests">
  <div
    *ngFor="let fav of requests.imdbId; index as i"
    class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
  >
    <div class="card">
      <img [src]="requests.poster[i]" class="card-img-top" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">{{ requests.title[i] }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f251ko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Nothing happend, almost the same error, I jumped from bed to my laptop, was hopping that this is it... :(

ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: And when I do a something like this:  

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gqv9Xfub8JZvIVbb52qRgB0DLlOFYhSs/view?usp=sharing    

It gives elements in console but in UI your *ngIF restricts, when I remove the *ngIf the same error appears...

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f251ko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Ok, your is working because your code is returning a array. This is console from your code:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A5TPdaXh_cLfUTSROVrfPW9f4NtBB75A/view?usp=sharing  But in my case in this spot (Prototype) I'm getting Object, that's why I'm getting the error. It's because my get request in .Net, I tried milion combination and nothing is helpping :/

Comment: give me the api, i will show you.

Comment: My .Net5 get request API code is in my question, or do You need something else?

Comment: this api, http://localhost:5002/api/Favorite/getUsersFavorite, not "http://localhost:5002/", what is your domain name

Comment: This is my complete backend, .net, in github: https://github.com/osmanagic12352/MyMoviesBackend

Comment: And this is the Front: https://github.com/osmanagic12352/MyMovies-Frontend

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you give for my project :D :D

Comment: i don't have .net framework, can you send only the object that  you get in api

Comment: If you mean the API result, I get this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1acStrlB7kJba1yyTTLWUIvr89ETrr7pF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: check it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f251ko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: copy the Html and paste your project. it will be work

Comment: BRILLIANT!!! Now it is working, this with index method working, great stuff!! And one of problems was that I wrote imdb and other stuff with first letter uppercase... stupid fails.... Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!!!

Comment: you can use css to capitalize: .title { text-transform: capitalize; }, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f251ko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: No, No, I don't have any problems anymore, only that if I go to my favorite page I must wait 10-15 seconds to make my movies appear.